# Generate 'Used by' report similar to mvn repository

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

We have 15-20 modules which uses the third party jars (available on maven). We have kept these jars as part of single pom using dependency management. Now, we want to generate report where we can get which module uses the the jar mentioned in third party pom.

Maven repository shows the '**Used by**' report for given artifact. We want to have similar functionality.

**Example** :- **spring-core** is used by **7676** artifacts based on the URL : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core

**Q.** How can we get the required information ? Do we have any plugin for such use case ?

Comment: Technically you can get this via maven-dependency-plugin:tree goal for your own project. If you like to do that in more global way you could check https://maven.apache.org/maven-indexer/ Apart from that `mvnrepository` is not related to the Maven project nor to the Apache Software Foundation also you could check https://search.maven.org/ which provides an REST API etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if I understood you the right way. But if you want to figure out the relation between the modules, you can get this by `mvn dependency:tree` of all modules, while you have to aggregate the count by yourself.

see [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)

Comment: any idea how mvn repository does ? any plugin where we can provide multiple poms and it will calculate the 'used by' information ?

Comment: You would need a repository manager like nexus of jfrog providing such an analysis function